# How to print a unit in Ocaml? [beginner]

Tags: arrays, oop, output, ocaml

I am trying to write a chess game in ocaml. In my code, i have defined types, created a class to store (piece, colour, location) array in the lenght of 32 for each piece. Now i want to print my array out as string. I created two methods, one to make a chess board and put pieces as strings on it and other one to print it out. However, it gives me error as

```
Error: This expression has type string list array array -> unit
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a -> 'b, unit, string) format =
           ('a -> 'b, unit, string, string, string, string)
           CamlinternalFormatBasics.format6
```

I feel really stuck because i tried to make different methods such as, turning it in a string list or turning it an array of strings but it didn't work either. How can i print this array matrix out?

```
       method init =
       let b = Array.make_matrix 8 8 "_" 
       for i = 0 to 7 do b.(i).(1) <- ["P"] done;
       for i = 0 to 7 do b.(i).(6) <- ["p"] done;
             for i = 0 to 7 do b.(i).(2) <- ["."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."] done;
             for i = 0 to 7 do b.(i).(3) <- ["."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."] done;
             for i = 0 to 7 do b.(i).(4) <- ["."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."] done;
             for i = 0 to 7 do b.(i).(5) <- ["."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."; "."] done;
         for i = 0 to 7 do b.(i).(0) <- ["R"; "N"; "B"; "Q"; "K"; "B"; "N"; "R"] done;
         for i = 0 to 7 do b.(i).(7) <- ["r"; "n"; "b"; "q"; "k"; "b"; "n"; "r"] done; 

            method print = Printf.sprintf self#init board

    end;;
```

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `fmt` library that provides combinators on the top of the `Format` module (which is itself an enhanced version of Printf). A basic print function without customizing the separator would be:

```
let print a = Fmt.(array (array (list string))) Fmt.stdout a
```

It is hard to tweak further the printer since it is not clear why you have a matrix of list of chess pieces.

Without using the combinators, you can use  both `Array.iter` and `List.iter` to achieve similar result:

```
let print_list l= List.iter print_string l
let print_array a = Array.iter print_list a; print_newline ()
let print_matrix m = Array.iter print_array m
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few different problems.

First, your method `init` initializes an array `b` but doesn't do anything with it. Possibly you wanted to return the array `b` as a result. Or possibly you wanted to save `b` somewhere and return a unit value.

Second your method `print` uses `Printf.sprintf` incorrectly. The function `Print.sprintf` takes a format and then some values (as specified by the format). Your call:

```
Printf.sprintf self#init board
```

doesn't follow this requirement. First, there is no format. Second, the values are not the kind that the `Printf` module knows how to print. I'm not sure what `self#init` is supposed to return, but none of the obvious possibilities (an array or a unit value) can be printed directly by `Printf.sprintf`.

The value `board` isn't defined in your code fragment, but I would assume it's an array of some type. Again,  this can't be printed directly by `Printf.sprintf`.

Comment: I was going to write you some code, but I see that @octachron has already done so. Cheers!